# subset pandas DataFrame and split into 3 DataFrames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

How can I subset the pandas DataFrame by the values in one column? For example, I want to separate the dataset below by the names of each Company.

So I want to split the `keywords` data frame into 3 different data frames. 
I tried to def a function that would split the dataset by the name value in the column and then ran a for loop on the column for the function. However, it doesn't seem to work. 
Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

```
keywords = {'Company':['amazon', 'amazon', 'amazon', 'target' 'target' 'target', 'walmart', 'walmart', 'walmart'], 
'keywords':['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'rst', 'uvw', 'xyz'], 
'type':['article', 'blog', 'news', 'article', 'blog', 'news', 'article', 'blog', 'news']}

def key(name):
    key = keywords.loc[name, :]
    return

for h in keywords['Company']:
    key(h)
```

Answer (score 0):

the following assumes `df` is a dataframe loaded with your keywords data

```py
amazon_df = df.query('Company == "amazon"')
```

this will return a new dataframe where the company column matches the string 'amazon'. To pass in a variable to `df.query` string you prepand an `@` symbol to the variable name. [pandas.DataFrame.query docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

for example:

```py
def get_subset_df(df, company_name):
    return df.query('Company == @company_name')
```

Comment: what if I want to use this in a function? So that every time I add a new company name to the keywords data, I wouldn't have to manually change it.

Comment: get a unique list of companies, iterate through it and add the subset dataframe to a dictionary mapping company name to it's subset dataframe.

Comment: it seems to work, but how do I call these datasets? Where are they stored?

Comment: If you followed my suggestion you should have a dictionary where the keys are the company name string whose corresponding value is the "company" dataframe. To access the amazon dataframe in the company dataframe dictionary something akin to `company_df_dict['amazon']` would return the value (the amazon dataframe) for the key "amazon".